# real anaylsis: 2.4 completeness axiom

Tags: real-analysis

This is my first time using this website, so i'm sorry if I posted this in the wrong forum\section. can anyone help me prove this? I know that it's really simple that's why i'm having trouble with it. I'm thinking I would use the density theorem? but i'm not sure. any help is appreciated thanks!

show that:

if $a > 0$ and $r, s \in \mathbb{Q}$

$r < s\iff a^r < a^s$ when $a > 1$, and $r < s\iff a^r > a^s$ when $0 < a < 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/588038

Comment: Learn some [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for formatting your maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $r,s\in \mathbb{Q}$, one can write $r = x/y$ and $s = c/d$ for some $x,y,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d,y > 0$.

First consider the case when $a>0$. Then $$a^r < a^s \iff (a^{x/y})^{dy} < (a^{c/d})^{dy} \iff a^{xd} < a^{cy}.$$ Since $xd$ and $cy$ are both integers and $a>1$, we know $$
a^{xd}<a^{cy} \iff xd < cy \iff x/y < c/d.
$$

The case when $a<1$ is analogous.

Comment: thank u so much!